# Does matplotlib axes know which figure it is in?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I use something like

```
ax.get_figure()
```

to get the figure which the ax is in.

Comment: please elucidate further.

Comment: Yes. Exactly what you suggested.

Comment: yes, `fig = ax.figure`

Comment: To help learn things like this interactively I suggest taking a look at [ipython](http://ipython.org/). This provides an interactive prompt so you can use `tab` on an object to see what attributes it has and even see help by `ax.get_figure?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, `Axes` need to know what figure they are is for the transform stack to work properly.  To get at this information, `Axes` object have an attribute:

```
fig = ax.figure
```

which is the figure the axes is in.  As a side note, you can not easily move axes between figures or artists between axes for exactly this reason.

Comment: If I have an `Axes` object, and I take care of changing the `figure` attribute, is it then  possible to me the `Axes` object into another `figure`?

Comment: @DrV There are many more connection between the figure and the axes than just this attribute (I can not enumerate them off the top of my head). In principle you _can_ re-do all of the plumbing, but it is not convenient nor have I seen a compelling case as to _why_ you would want to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then it is as I expected. I just wanted to make sure. I don't have a use case, either; it's just my cat-killer (curiosity).